# Testing GraphQL schema throws a TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, graphene-python

This is my first experience with Graphene, I suppose my question is so obvious...

But when I am Testing GraphQL schema in this [step-by-step tutorial](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/sqlalchemy/en/latest/tutorial/#testing-our-graphql-schema) on last step it throws a `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'String' and 'NoneType'`

[image: view from console]

Where I am wrong?
All the previous steps are ok.

Answer (score 0):

try this for `schema.py`

```
import graphene
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType
from models import (
    Department as DepartmentModel,
    Employee as EmployeeModel,
)


class Department(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = DepartmentModel


class Employee(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_employees = graphene.List(Employee)
    all_departments = graphene.List(Department)

    def resolve_employees(self, info):
        query = Employee.get_query(info)
        return query.all()

    def resolve_departments(self, info):
        query = Department.get_query(info)
        return query.all()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```